# How to change default black color of Grafana

Tags: grafana

As the Grafana Dashboard comes with Default black back ground color. It is possible to change the color to some other color of user choice?

Comment: Hi ask is for changing color for anonymous user. I am looking the change for every body.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What version are you using? If you're using > v3.x, you'll be able to set a default theme for the main organisation.

Set it to the light theme and you're good.

Comment: Hi Paraj, I am using version 4.0.0. I can see that   default_theme=dark. What are the possible options to set i have?

Comment: Hi, I can see that only two options can be set, either dark or light. Thanks.

Comment: You can compile your own user color choice by editing either the dark or the light css file and then setting the default organization to use that. Grafana by default only comes with the dark or the light theme.

Comment: in /etc/grafana/grafana.ini  uncomment line and set default_theme = light

Answer (score 8):

In Grafana Home Dashboard:

> ***Configuration** -> Preferences -> UI Theme -> Light*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use docker with environment config，you can add `GF_USERS_DEFAULT_THEME = light`

Answer (score 3):

In the grafana URL link, you can add `&theme=light`.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom left corner, above the help button, there is a little icon. Click on it and edit your preferences.