# How do you change the background colour in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

I want to modify the dark theme in Grafana so that it uses `#000000` as the background colour.

I have seen "[How to change default black color of Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006070/how-to-change-default-black-color-of-grafana)", however those answers only tell you how to choose between the light and the dark themes.

I also see that [How to Customize Your Grafana Theme](https://www.neteye-blog.com/2017/12/how-to-customize-your-grafana-theme/) recommends editing the `_variables.dark.scss` file, however I cannot see where this is located, as it is not in the `public/sass` directory as the post suggests.

Finally, I also see that `_variables.dark.generated.scss` tells you to *Edit grafana-ui/src/themes/_variables.dark.scss.tmpl.ts to update template*, however I cannot find that file either.

Could you point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: I am facing the same situation. Have you found a solution other than the Boom plugin? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Boom Theme](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/yesoreyeram-boomtheme-panel) plugin worked for me with Grafana 6.7.1

Installation:

```
grafana-cli plugins install yesoreyeram-boomtheme-panel
service grafana-server restart
```

Go to certain Dashboard and add new Panel. Select "Boom Plugin".

Enter this under "Custom Style / CSS Override"

```
.panel-container {
  background-color: #000000; 
}
.dashboard-container {
  background-color: #000000; 
}
.navbar {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

The Boom Theme plugin documentation is here: <strike>https://github.com/yesoreyeram/yesoreyeram-boomtheme-panel/tree/master/docs</strike> Documentation no longer exists, see the [GitHub readme file](https://github.com/yesoreyeram/yesoreyeram-boomtheme-panel) instead.

P.S. In case you are embedding Grafana's dashboard/panel, check for "allow_embedding = true" under "[security]" section in grafana.ini and use &kiosk parameter in a URL to avoid menus

Comment: where do we find all the css classes we need to override?

Answer (score 1):

I found the same sites as you and was frustrated at first. Fortunately I then found the Grafana plugin "Boom Theme Panel" (https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/yesoreyeram-boomtheme-panel).

It allows you to define a background image or to override the background color under "Custom Style / CSS Override" with the following settings:

```css
.main-view {
  background-color: #000000; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can do this in Grafana v10 without installing a plugin.

- Add a text panel
- Select HTML mode
- Add CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background-color: green; 
    /* You can also use more advanced CSS for background patterns etc. */
  }
</style>
```

- Make the panel invisible by turning on the transparent background option.

(It seems this was also the approach used by the (now deprecated) "Boom Theme Panel" plugin.)

The most obvious downside of this approach is that you have to add this panel to every dashboard. However, if you make it into a library panel, you can later change the background in all dashboards 1 one central place.

From [Is Grafana theming possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488902/is-grafana-theming-possible):

> If you see raw code in text panel display, then you might need to set
> disable_sanitize_html in your grafana settings.