# Is Grafana theming possible?

Tags: css, sass, grafana

I am using the latest version of Grafana (10 as of the time of writing this). I'd like to embed some of my Grafana panels in another place / my own website. However, the light and dark themes of Grafana differ from my website's remaining custom panels vastly.

Does Grafana support / allow theming? I'd like to build a custom theme that would be used on the embedded panels on my website only, while keeping them the same as the rest of Grafana when browsing on Grafana itself. Is that even possible? If not, what is possible in regards of this topic (maybe a plugin such as BoomTheme, but it doesn't seem to work as nothing changes / happens when I install it and I cannot find it anywhere in the settings)? I was searching throughout Grafana docs, but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana does not natively support theming individual panels for embedded use. You may need to use custom CSS or custom panel plugins to achieve specific theming for embedded panels on your website.

Comment: I figured that much so far, but none of the plugins feature the stuff that I need and I cannot "inject" my own CSS into Grafana unless I recompile Grafana altogether, which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to add a text panel with HTML mode in your dashboard and add some custom CSS as content, for example:

```html
<style type="text/css">
[data-testid="header-container"] {
  background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

[image: text panel]

*Edit*: if you see raw code in text panel display, then ou might need to set [disable_sanitize_html](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#disable_sanitize_html) in your grafana settings.

[image]

then all the dashboard including panels are styled with this CSS and this is a sample panel in kiosk mode with path https://[grafana server domain]/dashboard/new?orgId=1&viewPanel=1&kiosk

[image: kiosk mode panel]

Comment: Unfortunately, Grafana doesn't apply that. It just renders the CSS as plain text in the panel. I tried with using `<script>` tags and injecting some JS code in there and the result is the same.

Comment: @JrDeveloper It works for me. You might need to set [disable_sanitize_html](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#disable_sanitize_html) in your grafana config.

Comment: Yes, but I need to show charts and stuff and then change the colors of their series, background, etc. The text panel just displays the HTML that I want, but my requirement was to embed an existing panel and then change its color scheme.

Comment: I edited my post, the CSS in the text panel is applied to the full dashboard page including the graph panels, not only to the text panel.

Comment: Am I missing something? [clicky](https://i.imgur.com/3FL7U2r.png)

Comment: I added screenshots. Have you checked disable_sanitize_html in your grafana settings?

Comment: That does indeed seem to work when it comes to styling the whole dashboard page, but after embedding it, the styles are not applied, to the embedded panel (I am not embedding the text panel, but another one), so it kind of doesn't work for my use case.

Comment: If you describe what you mean by "embedded panel" in the question, it would help to get a more meaningful answer. What kind of grafana feature are you using for the "embedded panel"? Is it something different from the "viewPanel" of the graph in my answer?

Comment: So, let's say I have a panel in a dashboard and I want to embed that specific panel on a 3rd party website (e.g my personal home webpage). I go to the panel, and click on `Share`. I copy the embed `<iframe>` and paste it in my personal's page HTML or whatever, and the panel displays just fine. But I want the color palette to match something else rather than Grafana's default dark | light. 

This is how the embed panel popup looks: [clicky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrZ81.png).

Comment: In that case you can try to apply the solutions of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).

Comment: I did try that, but Grafana blocks the injection `Blocked a frame with origin "http:127.0.0.1:5500" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` In my `custom.ini`, I did set `allowed_origins = "*"` but it still blocks the injection, so I couldn't do anything. I have a simple .html file (for testing purposes):
```<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/d-solo/c4de2d57-70b9-4c7d-b1bd-d36a53cd69be/dashboard-for-html-panel?orgId=1&panelId=4"
  onload="applyCustomTheme(this)"></iframe>```

Comment: I have a simple .html file (for testing purposes):

```function applyCustomTheme(iframe) {
  var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  var customStyles = '#pagetop { background: green !important; }';
  var styleTag = doc.createElement("style");
  styleTag.innerHTML = customStyles;
  doc.head.appendChild(styleTag);
}
```